# I am changing the state, but subscribed components are not rendered

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I find the index number of the element, change a value in that index  in order not to break the order in the array, dispatch it as a new array but subscribed components are not rendered.

```
     var userPhotoIndex = userPhotos.findIndex(p => p.photoId === photoId) 
    
     if (userPhotoIndex > -1) {
        userPhotos[userPhotoIndex].likeCount -= 1;
        dispatch(getUserPhotosSuccess([...userPhotos]))
      }
```

Actually, the state changes in redux extension, but the subscribed component does not.

**Hook**

```
function LikeButton({ photo, photoId, setlikeCount }) {
const [isLike, setIsLike] = useState(false)
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const history = useHistory()
const isLogged = useSelector(state => state.isLoggedReducer);
const userPhotos = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.userPhotos);

const onClick = () => {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("photoId", photoId)
    if (!isLike) {
        axios.post(LIKE_API_URL, fd, { headers: authHeaderObj() }).then(() => {
            setIsLike(!isLike);
            setlikeCount(!isLike);
            var userPhotoIndex = userPhotos.findIndex(p => p.photoId === photoId)
            if (history.location.pathname.includes("me/" + profileFlowState.Likes)) {
                if (userPhotoIndex > -1) {
                    userPhotos[userPhotoIndex].likeCount += 1;
                    dispatch(getUserPhotosSuccess([...userPhotos]))
                }
            }

        }).catch(err => redirectErrPage(err, dispatch));
    }
    else {
        axios.delete(deleteLikePath(photoId), { headers: authHeaderObj() }).then(() => {
            setIsLike(!isLike);
            setlikeCount(!isLike);
            var userPhotoIndex = userPhotos.findIndex(p => p.photoId === photoId)
            if (history.location.pathname.includes("me/" + profileFlowState.Likes)) {
                if (userPhotoIndex > -1) {
                    userPhotos[userPhotoIndex].likeCount -= 1;
                    dispatch(getUserPhotosSuccess([...userPhotos]))
                }
            }
        }).catch(err => redirectErrPage(err, dispatch));
    }

}

useEffect(() => {
    if (isLogged) {
        axios.get(getIsLikePath(photoId), { headers: authHeaderObj() }).then(res => setIsLike(res.data))
    }
}, [isLogged, photoId])
if (!isLogged) {
    return <Button onClick={() => history.push("/login")} variant="outline-primary" style={{ borderRadius: 0 }} className="btn-sm">
        <i className="fa  fa-thumbs-up" style={{ fontSize: 16 }}></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Beğen</Button>
}
return (
    <Button onClick={onClick} variant={isLike ? "primary" : "outline-primary"} style={{ borderRadius: 0 }} className="btn-sm">
        <i className="fa  fa-thumbs-up" style={{ fontSize: 16 }}></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Beğen</Button>
)}
```

Below I am rendering a subscribed hook.

**Subscribed**

```
function UserPhotos({ userId }) {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const setFalseIsLoading = () => setIsLoading(false);
useEffect(() => { dispatch(getUserPhotosApi(userId, setFalseIsLoading)); }, [userId, dispatch])

const userPhotos = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.userPhotos)

return <div className="mt-3">{isLoading ? <Loading /> : <div>
    <MapPhotoCard removeButton={true} refreshPhotos={(id) => {
        dispatch(getUserPhotosSuccess([...userPhotos.filter(p => p.photoId !== id)]))
    }} photos={userPhotos} /></div>}
</div>}
```

Comment: Can you share the full component code? is `userPhotos` a state variable?

Comment: yes I am getting the current status  `const userPhotos = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.userPhotos);`

Comment: I need the full component code to help. Firstly, I can say you should never mutate your state variable without dispatching an action like you do in `userPhotos[userPhotoIndex].likeCount -= 1;` this is problematic. You can update your question to include more code, if you want

Comment: But I'm dispatching it as a new array. Don't you think it should change?

Comment: @AliYıldızöz You mutate the redux state in the component and then dispatch an action with the mutated value. You should return a new state from the reducer instead, [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is some information how you can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem: Mutating The State

#### Copying Too Late

```
dispatch(getUserPhotosSuccess([...userPhotos]))
```

You are dispatching your action with a copy of the array, but that's *after* you already mutated the state so it does not help.

#### Shallow Copies

Your array contains a bunch of objects, but behind the scenes your array contains *references* to the objects.  When you clone the array with `[...userPhotos]` you get a new array which contains all of the same object references.  So you when you set a property like `likeCount` on one of these objects, you are also setting that property on that object in the redux state.

### Solution: New Object in a New Array

In order to avoid mutations, we must return a new array with a new object for the photo that you are updating.  It is not necessary or desirable to perform a deep copy of the entire array.  The photos which you are not changing can stay the same.  A deep copy would cause unnecessary re-rendering of data which has not changed.

A [common solution](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array) here is to use `Array.prototype.map()`.  For the photo which matches the `photoId` we return a new photo object.  All other elements of the array stay the same.

```
const newPhotos = userPhotos.map((photo) =>
  photo.photoId === photoId
    ? {
        ...photo,
        likeCount: photo.likeCount + 1
      }
    : photo
);
dispatch(getUserPhotosSuccess(newPhotos));
```

### Suggestion: More Specific Actions

This sort of updating is usually done in the reducer rather than in the component.  Why is it necessary to return an array of every photo in response to a "like" or "unlike" action?

I recommend dispatching actions with the minimal amount of data possible.  Then in your reducer you can apply these changes.  Depending on the data structure of your state, you might need to know the user in order to update the photos for that user or you might just need to know the photo id.

Here we are passing the changed properties of a photo.  The reducer will combine them with the existing properties.  This action is good because it has a lot of uses while still requiring little data.

```
{ type: "UPDATE_PHOTO", payload: { photoId: _id_, changes: { likeCount: _newCount_ } }
```

You can make liking into its own action.  You could have separate actions for like and unlike which you handle separately in the reducer.  This is not my personal favorite.

```
{ type: "LIKE_PHOTO", payload: { photoId: _id_ } }
{ type: "UNLIKE_PHOTO", payload: { photoId: _id_ } }
```

The implementation in the reducer is a lot easier if you have a shared action for like and unlike with a property `change` that has a value of `1` or `-1`. The reducer handles both the same way by adding the `change` to the existing like count.  You can combine this with action creator functions to get the separation.

```
({ type: "UPDATE_LIKES", payload: { photoId: _id_, change: 1 } })
```

```
const likePhoto = (photoId) => ({ type: "UPDATE_LIKES", payload: { photoId, change: 1 } })
const unikePhoto = (photoId) => ({ type: "UPDATE_LIKES", payload: { photoId, change: -1 } })
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an important issue that I want to mention:

## Changing redux state

---

In this case you have a state variable, namely, `userPhotos` which resides in redux store. `userPhotos` is a variable of type array, and changing the `likeCount` via the line `userPhotos[userPhotoIndex].likeCount -= 1;` is an anti-pattern. Ideally, you want to clone the array first with one of two ways:

#### Using split operator

```
const userPhotosCopy = [...userPhotos]
userPhotosCopy[userPhotoIndex].likeCount -= 1
/*or userPhotosCopy.splice(userPhotoIndex, 1, {...userPhotosCopy[userPhotoIndex], likeCount: likeCount - 1 }]*/
```

#### Using lodash

```
import _ from 'lodash'
const userPhotosCopy = _.cloneDeep(userPhotos)
```

### Fetching on useEffect

Once you update your `userPhotos`, in your Subscribed component, ideally you want a pattern like this:

```
const userPhotos = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.userPhotos);

return(
   // use userPhotos in whatever way you like
)
```

Not sure what is the `getUserPhotosSuccess` action is doing, but it seems like you are not getting the updated `userPhotos` object in your subscribed component

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Yes. Totally true. The state changes when I change the `photoUrl` or `username` but `likeCount`does not change. I think this is caused by something else. I use `userphotos` here `photos={userPhotos}`

Comment: yeah you could try using userPhotos.map(photo => ... to render your photos if that is what you want